# jQuery add remove class to id IF

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a noob with jQuery and would like to ask how to write proper syntax. I am using a javascript plugin that recognizes the bg color and uses a class to contrast the text. It has 4 css options light, dark, light-complex, dark-complex. I would like to use my .dark-overlay when the #globaltext has a class .background--light.background--complex. And none if it doesnt have a class. could someone possibly help me? This was my best attempt at it...

I am working in WordPress thats my I'm using jQuery instead of $

```
 jQuery( "#globaltext" ).hasClass( ".background--light.background--complex" ){
 jQuery( "#overlay" ).addClass( "dark-overlay" );
 }
 }
```

Comment: You just need an `if` statement... What's blocking you?

Comment: `if ( id hasClass){
addClass
}else{
doSomething else
}`  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you just need an `If`statement.

```
if(jQuery( "#globaltext" ).hasClass( "background--light.background--complex" )){
            jQuery( "#overlay" ).addClass( "dark-overlay" );
}else{
 // do somthing else
}
```

Comment: you need remove dot from ".background--light.background--complex"

Comment: Yes, as @LTasty mentioned, you don't need the dots, but a space between the classnames would also help :).

Comment: I am trying to get your solution to work but it just doesnt add the class to it. The plugin is using document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () and is changing the class when you are scrolling for example. I dont know if this changes the situation or if Im just hopeless

Answer (score 0):

You need use if stantement and parameter of hasClass without .

```
if( jQuery( "#globaltext" ).hasClass("background--light.background--complex")){
     jQuery( "#overlay" ).addClass( "dark-overlay" );
}
```